# Why does this code cause an error? (Use of undeclared ideatifier '_maxConcurrentRequestCount') in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Why does this code cause an error in XCode? (Use of undeclared ideatifier '_maxConcurrentRequestCount')

```
@interface HTTPKit : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger maxConcurrentRequestCount;
@end

@implementation HTTPKit

- (void)setMaxConcurrentRequestCount (NSInteger)maxConcurrentRequestCount {

}

- (NSInteger)maxConcurrentRequestCount {
    if (!_maxConcurrentRequestCount) {
        _maxConcurrentRequestCount = 1;
    }
    return _maxConcurrentRequestCount;
}

@end
```

Please help me resolve this problem.

why we must use code below to fixed it?

```
@synthesize maxConcurrentRequestCount = _maxConcurrentRequestCount;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you override the default getter and setter of a property then the property won't be automatically synthesized and no iVar will be created to back the property.

You can either manually synthesize the property like you said or create your own iVar:

```
@interface HTTPKit : NSObject {
    NSInteger _maxConcurrentRequestCount;
}

...
@end
```